# getting an ajax error after returning from generic handler

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, knockout.js

I think I am posting my json data successfully to the server because when I debug on the server it looks fine to me. It's only when it comes back I guess I'm getting the error on the callback. But the error doesn't make sense to me.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: How are you sending the data back to the page? Where is that code?

Comment: I'm actually not sending anything back in this test of mine (void)

Comment: Isn't is expecting to receive something back? Seems like jQuery is trying to parse your JSON and you're not sending JSON back to it. Try sending SOMETHING (JSON) back to it and maybe it'll be able to parse it.

Comment: Thanks that was it. Please add it as an answer and I'll check it : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it expecting to receive something back? Seems like jQuery is trying to parse your JSON and you're not sending JSON back to it. Try sending SOMETHING (JSON) back to it and maybe it'll be able to parse it.

Comment: In this particular example, I just had to remove data type option. Thanks for the help!